# How to generate random a - z letter(1 letter) in JavaScript without typing all letters?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to generate random a - z letter(1 letter) in JavaScript without typing all letters. But I don't know how. I want to use `Math.floor(Math.random * ?)`. But I don't know what is ?. I want to use JavaScript in this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AZ Generator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="az-generator.js"></script>
    <button onclick="az()">Generate</button>
    <p id="p"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to do this without using random numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There're 2 things you need:

- Something to bridge the gap between numbers and characters and that could be [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
- Random number within a *proper* range to get one of *required* characters (for lower case letters that would be the range of 26 [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) chars starting from char code 97)

So, the solution could be as simple as that:

```js
const randomLetter = () => String.fromCharCode(0|Math.random()*26+97)

console.log(randomLetter())
```

If you need to extend that to get random string of desired length (say, 15 chars long), you may go like that:

```js
const randomLetter = () => String.fromCharCode(0|Math.random()*26+97)

const randomLineOfLetters = (lineSize) => () => Array(lineSize)
  .fill()
  .map(randomLetter)
  .join('')

const randomLineOf15Letters = randomLineOfLetters(15)
      
console.log(randomLineOf15Letters())
```

---

#### Bonus:

Since you haven't mentioned case sensitivity, you may pick the starting char code from either [a-z] or [A-Z] ranges, or randomly apply `.toUpperCase()`:

```js
const randomLetterRandomCase = () => {
  const aCharCode = 97
  const capitalACharCode = 65
  const alphabetSize = 26
  const startChar = Math.random() < 0.5
    ? capitalACharCode
    : aCharCode
    
  return String
    .fromCharCode(0|Math.random()*alphabetSize+startChar)
}

const randomlyCasedRandomLetter = () => {
  const aCharCode = 97
  const alphabetSize = 26
  const isUpperCase = Math.random() < 0.5
  const randomLetter = String
    .fromCharCode(0|Math.random()*alphabetSize+aCharCode)
    
  return isUpperCase
    ? randomLetter.toUpperCase()
    : randomLetter
}

const randomLineOfLetters = (lineSize, letterPicker) => Array(lineSize)
  .fill()
  .map(letterPicker)
  .join('')
 
 

      
console.log(randomLineOfLetters(15, randomLetterRandomCase))
console.log(randomLineOfLetters(15, randomLetterRandomCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a random number of 0 ... 25 and add 10 and convert the number to string with a base of `36`.

```js
function az() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 10).toString(36);
}

console.log(Array.from({ length: 50 }, az).join(''));
```